# How can you get the rendered row given a text range in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am trying to replicate the icon effect iBooks shows when a user adds a note. This note is off to the far right of the text on the same row as the text that was highlighted. I want one to show up next to each line of text that has a note. I am using a UITextView and I have attributed text to show what has been highlighted, but I can't figure out which rendered row of text has those attributes.

Most of the UITextView methods seem to deal with text ranges instead of rendered rows. Is there a way to get the rendered row in a UITextView given a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. For each item you want to show a icon next to, you substring your attributed text at the start of that range. Then, you get the bounding rect of that text and use that to calculate where to place your icon:

```
NSAttributedString *substring = [self.attributedText attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, location.unsignedIntegerValue)];

// Find the frame that would enclose the substring of text at the start of the range.
CGRect frame = [substring boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                       options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                       context:nil];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width + 10, self.frame.origin.y + frame.size.height - 20, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Note that this puts the icon to the right of the text.